# adding a where clause on an inner join

Tags: mysql, inner-join, where-clause

I have 2 tables : `registered_students` - cols: regnum AND `student` - cols: regnum, name

So I'm working on a query to select from both tables. It's working so far, but now I want to add a where clause to it, and it's  not returning any rows. Here is the query

```
SELECT registered_students.regnum
     , student.name
FROM registered_students
    INNER JOIN student ON registered_students.regnum=student.regnum
```

example data:

```
registered_students 1).reg3030 2). reg4032
              student 1).reg3030 John Doe 2).reg4032 Luke White
```

So I need to add a where clause like `WHERE regnum LIKE 'reg4%'`

Comment: Could you add sample rows to the question?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the alias as the column has same name in both the tables, try the following query:

```
SELECT registered_students.regnum, student.name 
FROM registered_students JOIN student ON registered_students.regnum=student.regnum
WHERE registered_students.regnum LIKE 'reg4%';
```

The output will also depend on the availability of data with `reg4` in both the tables. You could try the following if the above does not work:

- case insensitive matching, e.g. `WHERE LOWER(registered_students.regnum) LIKE 'reg4%'`
- `LEFT JOIN` if you want the data from either of these tables

**Update**

With the updated data, it might be because of whitespace or a dot in the beginning of the value, I would try the following:

```
SELECT registered_students.regnum, student.name 
FROM registered_students JOIN student ON TRIM(registered_students.regnum) = TRIM(student.regnum)
WHERE registered_students.regnum LIKE '%reg4%';
```

Comment: That means you probably don't have any data

Comment: No, I have data in there

Comment: Add the example data in the question then, as I have said already

Comment: It should work fine. Show us snapshot of you current result. @kingraphaII